# How to check if an item already exists in my list?

Tags: python, list, tkinter, listbox

I am creating a simple GUI application to manage unknown words while learning a new language. The application is called Vocabulary and it loads/saves words from/into an XML document. Nevertheless, whenever I want to add a word to the list(box), I want to perform a security check to see if the word already exists in my list.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def add_item(self):

        if len(self.listBox.curselection()) > 0:
            messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'Please make sure you have no words selected!')

        elif self.txt_WordOrPhrase['state'] == 'disabled':
            messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'Please make sure you refresh fields first!')
        else:
            if len(self.txt_WordOrPhrase.get("1.0", "end-1c")) == 0:
                messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'Please enter the word!')
            else:
                w = Word(self.get_word(), self.get_explanation(), self.get_translation(), self.get_example())
                if self.words: # check if an item already exists
                    self.words.append(w)
                    self.listBox.insert(END, w.wordorphrase)
                else:
                    messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'That word already exists in your vocabulary!')

                self.clear_all()
                self.sync()
                self.word_count()

        self.save_all()
```

In C#, I would do it like this:

```
if (words.Find(x => x.WordOrPhrase == w.WordOrPhrase) == null) {
    words.Add(w);
    listView1.Items.Add(w.WordOrPhrase);
}
```

Comment: This sounds extremely similar to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397908/removing-selected-items-from-the-listbox-and-from-the-list/43411309#43411309). Is this a school assignment or something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the entire solution:

```
def add_item(self):

        if len(self.listBox.curselection()) > 0:
            messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'Please make sure you have no words selected!')

        elif self.txt_WordOrPhrase['state'] == 'disabled':
            messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'Please make sure you refresh fields first!')
        else:
            if len(self.txt_WordOrPhrase.get("1.0", "end-1c")) == 0:
                messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'Please enter the word!')
            else:
                w = Word(self.get_word(), self.get_explanation(), self.get_translation(), self.get_example())
                if not any(x for x in self.words if x.wordorphrase == w.wordorphrase):
                    self.words.append(w)
                    self.listBox.insert(END, w.wordorphrase)
                else:
                    messagebox.showinfo('Notification', 'That word already exists in your vocabulary!')

                self.clear_all()
                self.sync()
                self.word_count()

        self.save_all()
```